# Trying to update table in sql server but not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to update table in sql server but it's not working. Here is my code

```
SqlConnection conn;
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Alumnidb"].ConnectionString;
    string userName;
    SqlCommand cmdProfile, cmdUpdate;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string UserId;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userName = Request.QueryString["UserName"].ToString();

        RetriveProfile();
    }

    protected void RetriveProfile()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        cmdProfile = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, UserId FROM UserProfile WHERE UserName=@UserName",conn);
        cmdProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",userName);
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmdProfile.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            TextBoxName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
            UserId = reader["UserId"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    protected void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("UPDATE UserProfile SET Name=@Name WHERE UserId=@UserId",conn);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId",UserId);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",TextBoxName.Text.ToString());
        conn.Open();
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteScalar();

        conn.Close();

    }
```

and .aspx file

```
Name: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="buttonUpdate" runat="server"  Text="UpDate" 
        onclick="buttonUpdate_Click"/>
```

It shows me the previous value as before updated. . i checked in sql server and there is also no change in there
What am i doing wrong?
Your help will be appreciated. . .Thanx

Comment: Try `cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: `userName` getting the value correctly?

Comment: Tried but still the same result

Comment: @PiLHA: Yes it do . . .i checked it in debug mode

Comment: what is datatype of `urserid` in database?

Comment: @AmitSingh: it's uniqueidentifier. . also it is PK in table

Comment: `UserId` keeps its value between sessions?

Comment: Enclose code in Try/Catch, and get the error message...

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Taking UserName from query string and then userId from table as mentioned in code

Comment: USE IsPostBack property in page load,I think the value of textbox is not persisting it taking the old one, find what the value exactly text box value showing in update method

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam I tried as answer below suggested but i got exception plz see the answr below

Comment: please check the value userid in update method, i think it must be null there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you fill all values in `Page_Load` even if you are in a postback. So if the user clicks on the update-button `Page_Load` is fired first, all values are loaded from database and you set the `TextBox.Text` value to the old value. So all changes are lost.

So use the `IsPostBack` property:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userName = Request.QueryString["UserName"].ToString();
    if(!IsPostBack)
        RetriveProfile();
}
```

Since you are getting the `UserID` from the sql query and you need that in the update you have several options. You could persist the userid across postbacks e.g. in `ViewState` or `Session`. This can be done in `RetriveProfile`.

```
protected void RetriveProfile()
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    cmdProfile = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, UserId FROM UserProfile WHERE UserName=@UserName",conn);
    cmdProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",userName);
    conn.Open();
    reader = cmdProfile.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        TextBoxName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
        UserId = reader["UserId"].ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Change the field `UserID` to be a property:

```
private string UserId {
    get { return (string)ViewState["UserID"]; }
    set { ViewState["UserID"] = value;}
}
```

Note that all variables are disposed at the end of every page's lifecycle due to the statelessness of HTTP. Therefore you need to persist it somewhere.

[**Nine options for managing persistent User State in your ASP.NET Application**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

Comment: The parameterized query '(@UserId nvarchar(4000),@Name nvarchar(10))UPDATE UserProfile SE' expects the parameter '@UserId', which was not supplied. Gives this error

Comment: are you able to get the value of @userid in update method, i think its null there

Comment: @user2517610: Since you are getting the `UserID` from the sql query you have several options. You could persist the userid across postbacks e.g. in ViewState or Session. This can be done in `RetriveProfile`.

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam: Yes it is null but i checked in debug mode it shows that reader["UserId"] has value but userid=null as i write the code userid=reader["UserId"] but still userid remains null

Comment: actually when you fire update method, page gets post back, and i think you have declare userid outside as integer or whatever, it gets re-initialize

Comment: if you can make the userid static then make it static id or put in viewstate at the time of retrieving and at the time of update get it back from viewstate, you will get your id

Comment: I replace the userId with UserName which also a unique field in the table and now it is giving the intended results. . .Thanx to all members who tried to help me thank you very much